# Smoothing Out Scroll To Top Then Fixed / Fixed Floating Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to put together a site that has a welcome-type screen followed by a header/navigation that scrolls to the top of the page and is then fixed, remaining at the top of the page as the user scrolls on. The solution I have works in most browsers, except in the desktop touch version of Chrome I can't stop the header/nav from bouncing around once it reaches the top. I've looked at at least 10 Stack Overflow questions that address this problem, and I've tried a lot of different tutorials and plugins but none of them seem to work for me. I know it's possible because the technique appears on http://laravel.com, and the header/nav is ROCK-SOLID when it reaches the top and becomes fixed. This is what I have now:

```
html {
  height: 100%; }

body {
  height: 100%; }

#welcome {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%; }

#header {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888888;
  height: 90px;
  opacity: .93;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; }
  #header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; }

#nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 2%; }
  #nav a {
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    padding-left: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    text-transform: uppercase; }

#about {
  height: 2000px; }


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <section id="welcome"></section>
  <header id="header" class="container">
    <nav id="nav">
      <a href="#">One</a>
      <a href="#">Two</a>
      <a href="#">Three</a>
      <a href="#">Four</a> 
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="about" class="container">
    </section>
  </main>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      var top = $(document).scrollTop();
      var viewport = $("#welcome").height();
      $('#header').toggleClass("fixed", top >= viewport);       
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: seems working fine for me, what do you mean by nav bouncing?

Comment: when i scroll down and the header becomes fixed it bounces around as I keep scrolling. Oddly enough, I don't have the same problem scrolling back up & down after I have scrolled past it as long as I have stopped the original scroll and started a new one. I should have mentioned that this doesn't happen in FireFox, just chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time, and this is no longer an issue, but at the time chrome was not able to keep this header in place without it appearing "jumpy". I was able to fix it by adding

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

to the .fixed class. Although this didn't have any bearing on the visual styles that were applied, using the transform property would cause chrome to treat it as a 3d element and devote more resources to it.

As I mentioned before, this doesn't seem to be an issue anymore, and I have since been able to remove this hack without the old problem recurring.

Answer (score 0):

May be jquery toggle make it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      var top = $(document).scrollTop();
      var viewport = $("#welcome").height();
        if (top >= viewport ) {
            $('#header').addClass("fixed");
        } else if ($('#header').hasClass('fixed')) {
        $('#header').removeClass('fixed')}
    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/molo4nik11/zvom6o5w/

Comment: I've tried this, and a few different variations of the conditional/addClass statement. The toggle and conditional both work no problem in jsFiddle, and in FireFox for that matter, but the Chrome browser can't handle it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is working solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/molo4nik11/zvom6o5w/3/

```
#header {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #888888;
  height: 90px;
  opacity: .93;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
}
#header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I've tried relative positioning and absolute. I tried floating the elements. A friend just told me to try and work around the height: 100%; values for html, body elements etc. I am planning on trying this out later tonight.